# Solid in one color table top

Tags: html, css

I have table and there is some space between every column. I want to make it solid, without any spaces. Here is my style:

```
<style>
tr, th, td {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:90%;background:transparent;}
table{ margin:0px auto; width:40%; font-size:11px;}
table tr{ line-height:16px;}
table th {background:#eaeaea; padding:50px;}
table tr th{ background:#eaeaea;color:#404040; padding:3px; font-weight:bold }
table tr td{ padding:3px 5px; border-bottom: 2px solid #eaeaea; text-align:center;background:#fff}
table tr.noborder td{border:none;}
</style>
```

I hope you understand what I want :)

Comment: I don't see any space between columns.

Comment: in the css 
`table { border-collapse : collapse }`

Comment: @KingKing I think he edit the "demo" code from w3schools.com, but it was not saved... then we can't read it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add to table **border-collapse: collapse;**
it displays only a single line